# pure virtual functions and inheritance

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I'm having problems with polymorphism and pure virtual functions. My main class

```
#include<memory>

class Shape
{
  public:
  Gdiplus::Point start; 
  Gdiplus::Point end;

  std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> m_pen;

  virtual void Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics & m_GraphicsImage) = 0;


  void setPen(std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> pen2);


  void setStart(int xPos, int yPos);

  void setEnd(int xCor, int yCor);

};
```

Then i have this class that derives from Shape. Line.h

```
 #pragma once


 #include<memory>

class Line: public Shape
{
public:
  void Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics & m_GraphicsImage);
}
```

This is my line.cpp.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Line.h"
#include "ShapeMaker.h"


void Line::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics & m_GraphicsImage)
{

  m_GraphicsImage.DrawLine(m_pen.get(),start.X,start.Y,end.X,end.Y);
}
```

On my main i declare a shared pointer of type Shape for polymorphism reasons

```
 std::shared_ptr<Shape> m_shape;
```

and then try and call functions for the Line.cpp but it doesn't work,

```
LRESULT CDrawView::OnLButtonDown(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)

{
int xPos= GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
start.X = xPos;
start.Y = yPos;


//Line line;
auto line = std::make_shared<Shape> (m_shape);
std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> myPen(pen.Clone());
line->setPen(myPen);
line->setStart(xPos,yPos);
return 0;
}

LRESULT CDrawView::OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
int xPos= GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
end.X = xPos;
end.Y = yPos;

//Pen pen(Color(0, 0, 255));
//Line line;
auto line = std::make_shared<Shape> (m_shape);
line->setEnd(xPos,yPos);
line->Draw(m_GraphicsImage);
m_shape.reset();


RedrawWindow();


return 0;
```

}
   Now I'm getting drawview.cpp(54): error C2371: 'line' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          \draw\drawview.cpp(53) : see declaration of 'line'

Comment: I'll warn you right now that using function *parameter names* using the `member-variable` naming nomenclature `m_xxxxx` is going to drive anyone that is used to dealing with Microsoft-centric coding practices **insane**. Kill that bird **now**.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is your constructor

```
std::make_shared<Shape> (m_shape);
```

Which is essentially new Shape (an abstract class). Instead you should use

```
std::make_shared<Line> (m_shape);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
void Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics & m_GraphicsImage)
```

should read

```
void Line::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics & m_GraphicsImage)
```

Without the `Line::` you are defining a free function called `Draw()` that happens to have the same signature as `Line::Draw()` but is otherwise unrelated to it.

Comment: I'm still getting error C2259: 'Shape' : cannot instantiate abstract class when i try to compile

Comment: As Kiley mentions, you are doing a std::make_shared to try to create a Shape instance. The thing is that Shape has a pure virtual Draw method, and you'd obviously want it that way. This also means that Shape can never be instantiated. You can have Shape pointers and Shape references, but, they should always point to the derived, non-abstract classes.

Comment: hey  @user2184879 that's what i want. But i currently have two different functions and i just want to create an instance of one and use it for both functions but i get a line redefinition error...

Comment: so @user2184879 how would you suggest going around that?

Answer (score 0):

The error is for instantiating Shape, which is abstract class.

The above syntax 'auto line = std::make_shared (m_shape);' is the culprit.

In this statement, you are trying to instantiate Shape class.

Refer to this
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/

for correct usage of casting between shared_ptr